# getting most effective use of NOT regexp_like

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

I am looking at ways to to use `NOT regexp_like` to exclude various terms from a string in the most efficient manner (as background, this data is used to find births that occurred outside the hospital system):

```
        regexp_like(note_text,'(birth|home|deliver|ambulance|car).{0,20}(deliv|birth|home|ambulance|car)','i')
and NOT regexp_like(note_text,'(apgar|CESAREAN|birth).{0,10}(minute|section)','i')
```

So I am doing a pile on of the `NOT regexp_like` to exclude cesarean births and apgar scores - am I better off to separate into like terms such as

```
and NOT regexp_like(note_text,'(apgar).{0,10}(minute)','i')
and NOT regexp_like(note_text,'(CESAREAN).{0,10}(section|operation)','i')
```

to make it more efficient?

Also as the `regexp_like` is an operator and not a function, is there is a way online to see what it is doing ?

Comment: Performance-wise, you should be fine wrapping the negated terms into a single one with regexen structured like yours. Note however that your two samples approaches differ ( `apgar section` would only be filtered by the first ). You may consult the query plan for nested queries with individual regexen ( ie. `( select y.note_text from ( select x.note_text from ( select from ... where regexp_like(note_text, <re #1>) ) x  where not regex_like ( x.note_text,  <re #2> ) ) y where not regex_like ( y.note_text,  <re #3> )` to reduce result set size before applying more complex filters.

Comment: Also perhaps `ca?esarian`.